# Determine if a function is accessed or invoked in the proxy handler

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I have a proxy handler like this:

```
let handler = {
        get: function(target, name) {
            let member = target[name];
            if (typeof member === 'function') {
                return function() {
                    //
                }
            }
            return member;
        }
    }
```

Whenever a method is called on Proxy object:

```
var obj = {
    foo: function() {
        //
    }
}

var p = new Proxy(obj, handler);
p.foo();
```

...It invokes the function that was returned from the `handler`'s getter. But the problem is, when the method is **accessed** rather than **invoked** like this:

```
p.foo;
```

The entire definition of the function is returned.

Is there any way by which I could check to see if the method is being accessed (`p.foo`) or invoked (`p.foo()`)? I am trying to achieve something like:

```
if (typeof member === 'function' && member.isBeingCalled()) {
    return function() {
        //
    }
}
```

Also, in case of `p.foo`, I would like to return the definition of `member` instead of the function that handler's getter returns.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible but in order to make it work you need to consider what happens when call a method

```
 o.foo()
```

as there is more going on than you might think.

The first operation is a property lookup that retrieves the value of the property having the key `"foo"` from the object `o`. Now, the value retrieved is itself an object, specifically a function object.

The second operation is the  invocation of that function  as a method by way of 
[function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). What this does is invoke the function with its `this` value bound to `o`.

Therefore, in order to achieve the desired behavior, one must proxy the value of the property `o.foo` rather than `o` itself. your proxy will use the apply trap to intercept and modify the invocation of the function what is the value of that property. This is described well by MDN. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/apply

Essentially you would write something like

```
const foo = o.foo;
const proxiedFoo = new Proxy(foo, {
  apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    if (thisArg) {
      // this function is being invoked as a method
    }
  }
});

o.foo = proxiedFoo;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with this is that from the perspective of an API consumer, I might not want to explicitly call apply `proxiedFoo.apply(o)`. I would expect `proxiedFoo()` to automatically go through the `if (thisArg){}` block.

Comment: If I understand your intent correctly it will. The name of Proxy's apply trap is misleading.

Comment: Please take a look:  https://jsbin.com/dukoqik/1/edit?js,console,output